# Cannot convert 'SDL_Rect' to 'const SDL_Rect*'

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2. I have SDL rects in a sprite class that I want to access in main for the `SDL_Render_copy()` function, but I keep getting this error:

> cannot convert 'SDL_Rect' to 'const SDL_Rect*' for argument '3' to 'int SDL_RenderCopy(SDL_Renderer*, SDL_Texture*, const SDL_Rect*, const SDL_Rect*)'

The inside of my sprite class looks like this:

```
Sprite::Sprite()
{
    //sprite clips

    gSpriteClips[0].h = 128;
    gSpriteClips[0].w = 128;
    gSpriteClips[0].x = 16;
    gSpriteClips[0].y = 144;
}

SDL_Rect Sprite::getSpriteClip(int x)
{
    return gSpriteClips[x];
}
```

And in main I have this:

```
SDL_RenderCopy( system.getRenderer(), system.getFullSpriteTexture(), sprite.getSpriteClip(0), &dest);
```

I have been tinkering around with this error forever, but I can only make it work the way below -- but I'd rather achieve this without this extra line of code:

```
SDL_Rect newrect = sprite.getSpriteClip(0);
SDL_RenderCopy( system.getRenderer(), system.getFullSpriteTexture(), &newrect, &dest);
```

Comment: In your working example at the bottom, you used the `&` operator to convert an `SDL_Rect` to an `SDL_Rect*`. You missed that step in the failing code.

Comment: @Tim Johns I've tried using &sprite.getSpriteClip(0) though then I get the error message: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

Comment: Yea I thought that might happen. What you need to do is return a pointer from the `getSpriteClip` function (and use `&` in the return statement)

Comment: `const SDL_Rect* Sprite::getSpriteClipPtr(int x) const { return gSpriteClips + x; }` ... `SDL_RenderCopy( system.getRenderer(), system.getFullSpriteTexture(), sprite.getSpriteClipPtr(0), &dest);`

Comment: @Kaiwen `&sprite.getSpriteClip(0)` will work if `getSpriteClip()` returns an `SDL_Rect` by reference instead of by value: `SDL_Rect& Sprite::getSpriteClipPtr(int x) { return gSpriteClips[x]; } ... SDL_RenderCopy(..., &sprite.getSpriteClipPtr(0), ...);` Otherwise, return the `SDL_Rect` by pointer instead, like MFisherKDX showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, this worked:

```
const SDL_Rect* Sprite::getSpriteClip(int x)
{
    return &gSpriteClips[x];
}

SDL_RenderCopy( system.getRenderer(), system.getFullSpriteTexture(), sprite.getSpriteClip(0), &dest);
```